# I have two Activity of same list item i want to sellect first list item valu

Tags: android, arrays, list

I have two Activities of same list item I want to select first list item value and then go to another Activity list item value at same position. My code is :

```
public class First extends Activity{

    ListView lv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.first);  

        lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        String[] values = new String[] {"aa","bb","cc","dd","ee","ff","gg","hh","ii","jj","kk","ll","mm","nn","oo","pp","qq","rr","ss","tt"};

        ArrayAdapter<String>ad=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,values);
        lv.setAdapter(ad);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {

                if(id==1) {   
                } 
            }
        }); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want correctly, in your OnItemClickListener, you can do this :

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {

    String value = values[position];
    Intent intent = new Intent (this, OtherActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(VALUE_EXTRA_NAME, value);
    intent.putExtra(POSITION_EXTRA_NAME, position);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Then in the OtherActivity's onCreate method, retrieve the String value and the position of the clicked item (you can scroll to the same position with setSelection(int position) :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String value = intent.getStringExtra(VALUE_EXTRA_NAME);
int positionClicked = intent.getIntExtra(POSITION_EXTRA_NAME,0);
listView.setSelection(positionClicked);
// do something with the String value
```

Comment: Intent not goes in to another activity                                                                            POSITION_EXTRA_NAME   ,                           VALUE_EXTRA_NAME  how get the valu of List this code is not working

Comment: I really don't understand what you mean, sorry ... Anyway, I've used this kind of pattern successfully hundreds of times, so I'm going to need more information than just "this code is not working" in order to help you resolve your issue...

Answer (score 0):

In `onItemClick` add

```
Intent intent = new Intent(First.this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("position", position);
startActivity(intent);
```

In `NextActivity.class`

```
int position;  
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) { 
   position= extras.getInt("position"); 
} 
yourListView.setSelection(position);
```

Comment: next activity which place i should add                                                                                 int position;
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); if (extras != null) { position= extras.getInt("position"); } setSelection(position);

Comment: listview.setSelection(position); after adding ListView